# Automatically run JavaScript code upon loading a specific website

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I've written scripts to filter out threads and posts in a programming forum by author.

But you need to post the code into the web console for each page individually.

I was wondering if it were possible and if so how (using either firefox or chrome), to set your browser up to run a specific script upon loading a specific site? Is it possible as an extension or plugin?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Google Chrome

> Tampermonkey is the most popular userscript manager for Google Chrome.

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox:

> Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.

Comment: There’re no alternatives to Internet Explorer (in my case, version 11)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [dotjs](https://github.com/defunkt/dotjs).

> dotjs is a Google Chrome extension that executes JavaScript files in `~/.js` based on their filename.
>
> If you navigate to `http://www.google.com/`, dotjs will execute `~/.js/google.com.js`.
>
> This makes it super easy to spruce up your favorite pages using JavaScript.

Comment: I've never used dotjs, but this seems like the most valid option. Or the user could create their own Chrome extension that uses "Content Scripts". https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: If OP only needs to customize one website, indeed your solution would be more appropriate. Could you add it as an answer.

Comment: But if I want to upload my javascript on existing website in such a way that all users can see the change then what to do @Aliou ? as all users can't have dotjs, greasemonkey or Tempermonkey

Comment: If the website is yours, you should include the javascript in it. Otherwise I don't think there is a clear solution.