# How can I run a piace of javacript code on a certain website automatically?

Tags: javascript, html

So I basically want to create a mini adblocker for a wesite. I have the snippet below which I can run in chrome and have a certain add removed. Is there a way to make it run automatically when the page is loaded?

```
var element = document.querySelector("[referrerpolicy='unsafe-url']");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Use a [userscript](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript).

Comment: Have you tried to wrap it in `window.onload = () => {var element = document.querySelector("[referrerpolicy='unsafe-url']"); element.parentNode.removeChild(element);}` ?

Comment: There are many Google results for this question. [Automatically run JavaScript code upon loading a specific website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707808/automatically-run-javascript-code-upon-loading-a-specific-website). As a new member, please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the searching section.